# What does /[\[]/ do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble googling this. In some code I see

```
name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
```

`/[\[]/` looks to be 1 parameter. What do the symbols do? It looks like it's replacing [] with `\[\]` but what specifically does `/[\[]/` do?

Comment: The real question is why they're using a character class to match a single `[`

Comment: @friedo I guess they don't know what `[...]` is character class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax `/…/` is the [literal regular expression syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). And the regular expression `[\[]` describes a character class (`[…]`) that’s only character the `[` is). So `/[\[]/` is a regular expression that describes a single `[`.

But since the global flag is not set (so only the first match will be replaced), the whole thing could be replaced with this (probably easier to read):

```
name.replace("[", "\\[").replace("]","\\]")
```

But if all matches should be replaced, I would probably use this:

```
name.replace(/([[\]])/g, "\\$1")
```

Answer (score 10):

It's a regular expression that matches the left square bracket character.

It's a weird way to do it; overall it looks like the code is trying to put backslashes before square brackets in a string, which you could also do like this:

```
var s2 = s1.replace(/\[/g, '\\[').replace(/]/g, '\\]');
```

I think.

Answer (score 3):

/[[]/ defined a character range which includes only the ']' character (escaped), you are correct that is replaced [] with [].

Comment: hrm ... replaces [ and ] with their escaped versions

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` is in regex itself used to denote a collection of to-be-matched characters. If you want to represent the actual `[` or `]` in regex, then you need to escape it by `\`, hence the `[\[]` and `[\]]`. The leading and trailing `/` are just part of the standard JS syntax to to denote a regex pattern.

After all, it replaces `[` by `\[` and then replaces `]` by `\]`.

Comment: I guess inside [ ] a [ is not a meta char. [[] is a valid char class which matches only [